# I am trying to call the other contract which is already deployed on the blockchain. But when I try compiling it with remix , it doesn't compile

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix

I am trying to call the other contract which is already deployed on the blockchain. But when I try compiling it with remix , it doesn't compile

```
contract Othersurround {

 function getDetailsFromSurroundContract(address _contractAddress)public view returns(address,string memory,string memory,string memory,string memory,string memory){
   // surround is the name of the deployed contract 
  surround other = surround(_contractAddress);// ***Here is the error - DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
                                         surround other = surround(_contractAddress);***//
                                         ^-------^ 
    address  wallet_address = other.getUser();  
    string  userId = other.getUser();
    string  first_name = other.getUser();
    string  last_name = other.getUser();
    string  email_id = other.getUser();
    bool set = other.getUser();
    string private_key = other.getUser();
    
    return(wallet_address,userId,first_name,last_name,email_id,private_key);
    
 }
}
```

Comment: U need to import the interface of that contract

Comment: do you have its interface? is it another contract of you?

Comment: Yes its the other contract of me how do I convert my other contract to an interface as it contains modifier as well as functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the contract.
Contracts name start always with capital letter

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0; // or your solidity version

import "./Surround.sol"; // the path to the other contract

contract Othersurround {

   function getDetailsFromSurroundContract(address _contractAddress) public view returns(address, string memory, string memory, string memory, string memory, string memory) {
     // surround is the name of the deployed contract 
     Surround other = Surround(_contractAddress); // correct
     address  wallet_address = other.getUser(); // wrong
     string  userId = other.getUser(); // wrong
     string  first_name = other.getUser(); // wrong
     string  last_name = other.getUser(); // wrong
     string  email_id = other.getUser(); // wrong
     bool set = other.getUser(); // wrong
     string private_key = other.getUser(); // wrong
     return(wallet_address,userId,first_name,last_name,email_id,private_key);
   }
}
```

Now to the other problems :-) ->

- don't save private key on the blockchain
- don't save first name and last name and email on the blockchain
- the "other.getUser()" is not correct or the usage of it is wrong

if the getUser method in the "Surround.sol" smart contract returns a list of values,
then you need to do something like this:

```
function getDetailsFromSurroundContract(address _contractAddress) public view returns(address, string memory, string memory, string memory, string memory, string memory){
  address wallet_address;
  string userId;
  string first_name;
  string last_name;
  string email_id;
  boolean set;
  string private_key;
  (wallet_address, userId, first_name, last_name, email_id, set, private_key);
  return(wallet_address,userId,first_name,last_name,email_id,private_key);
}
```

Comment: sorry but this is wrong as I am trying to access my other contract which is already deployed on the blockchain and you cant just by using import.

Comment: Copy the code of the already deployed contract and place it in a file in the same directory. U will not deploy it again, u only need to make the code visible to ur contract @georgesingh